# sharp lower bound for n points approximate n+1 points in 2-dimensional space

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

For given distinct n+1 points in 2-dimensional space, we approximate them by n points. What is a sharp lower bound for this approximation? Precisely, assume distinct $x_1,\cdots,x_{n+1}\in \mathbb R^2$. We consider the estimation 
$$ \min_{\hat x_1,\cdots,\hat x_n\in \mathbb R^2}||\eta(\hat x_1,\cdots,\hat x_n)||_{\infty} \geq C(n) d_{\min}^n$$
where $d_{\min}=\min_{i\neq j}|x_i-x_j|$ (Euclidean distance) and 
$$
\eta(\hat x_1,\cdots,\hat x_n)=\begin{pmatrix}
|x_1-\hat x_1|\cdots|x_1-\hat x_n|\\
|x_2-\hat x_1|\cdots|x_2-\hat x_n|\\
\vdots\\
|x_{n+1}-\hat x_1|\cdots|x_{n+1}-\hat x_n|\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
What is the sharp estimate of $C(n)$?

Besides, I've solved the problem for dimension 1. I can share my proof if anyone interested. It depends on the order relation in 1-dimensional space. This is why finding a sharp bound in dimension 2 becomes much harder.

Comment: What is $(x_1-\hat x_1)\cdots(x_1-\hat x_n)$? Do you mean $|x_1-\hat x_1|\cdots|x_1-\hat x_n|$? And by $|x_i-x_j|$ in the definition of $d_\min$ do you mean the Euclidean distance?

Comment: I have specified it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to minimize? From your notation it looks like you want to minimize the product of the distances. I don't think that works very well because one of the $\hat{x}_i$ could be exactly equal to one of the $x_i$. It would be better to minimize the sum of distances or the sum of squares of distances.

Comment: Because we consider the $\infty$-norm of $\eta$, it doesn't matter that some $\hat x_j$ could be exactly some $x_i$.